# Filtered Running Total

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to get a running total of a count value in a table, but I need to have the filters I created to apply.

Basically I have 2 tables.

Table one is a user table which contains the user email (useremail) address and the user country (usercountry)

Table two contains the user email (useremail) and a date when they signed an agreement (Created)

I created a measure like this, which gets the user email from the signup table and gives me the running total, but when I apply a filter to the report, the sign up count does not change. It completely ignores the filter

```
Sign ups = 
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT(  'SignUps'[useremail] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLselected ( 'SignUps' ),
        'SignUps'[Created] <= MAX ( 'SignUps'[Created] )
    )
)
```

There is a relationship between the two tables where users(useremail) matches sign ups(useremail) One to One and cross filter both directions

Basically the chart below never changes regardless of the usercountry I filter by
Sign Up Chart.

[image]

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need ALLSELECTED unless you are showing visual total.

Remove ALLSELECTED and just pass a table so it can be filtered using your slicer.

```
Sign ups =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'SignUps'[useremail] ),
    FILTER (
        'SignUps',
        'SignUps'[Created] <= MAX ( 'SignUps'[Created] )
    )
)
```

[Read ALLSELECTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax)